# From infinitesimal momentum volume to infinitesimal rapidity & tranverse momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, differentiation, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to derive a relationship given in a paper which is used to obtained a differential cross-section distribution in function of rapidity and transverse momentum of final state particles,

$$
\frac{d^3 p}{E}=dyd^2p_t.
$$

Since $p_t$ is the transverse momentum, once I choose the beam to be in the $z$ direction, the momentum volume can be written as $d^3p=dp_zd^2p_t$ (where I used $dp_xdp_y=d^2p_t$). Now, there is a direct relationship between rapidity and the longitudinal momentum given by the well known formula,
$$
y=\frac{1}{2}\log\left({\frac{E+p_z}{E-p_z}}\right).
$$

Differentiation with respect to $p_z$ returns
$$
\frac{dy}{dp_z}=\frac{E}{E^2-p_z^2},
$$
or
$$
\frac{dp_z}{E}=\frac{E^2-p_z^2}{E^2}dy,
$$
which, in the end, gives me,
$$
\frac{d^3p}{E}=\frac{E^2-p_z^2}{E^2}dyd^2p_t.
$$

I'm doing something wrong but I can't see it.

P.S. No assumptions seemed to have been made except for the fact that they treat the scattering in the CM from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The mistake is in the third equation $\frac{dy}{dp_z}$ because I treated the energy $E$ as if it was independent of $p_z$. The correct answer is,
$$
dy=dp_z\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial p_z}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial E}\frac{dE}{dp_z}\right),
$$
Using the fact that $E^2=p_t^2+p_z^2+m^2$ and that $p_t$, $p_z$ and $m$ are independent of each others, the expression between the parentheses is so that
$$dy=\frac{dp_z}{E}.$$

Thanks